# Find next non-blank row in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nonblank

Given a Pandas dataframe of

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None,1,None,None,2,None], 'b': [None,None,None,3,None,4]})

     a    b
0  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  3.0
4  2.0  NaN
5  NaN  4.0
```

I want to return the position and value of the next non-blank `b` after a non-blank `a`, and put this *position* and *value* into new columns next to the non-blank `a`, so:

```
     a    b position  value
0  NaN  NaN      NaN    NaN
1  1.0  NaN        3    3.0
2  NaN  NaN      NaN    NaN
3  NaN  3.0      NaN    NaN
4  2.0  NaN        5    4.0
5  NaN  4.0      NaN    NaN
```

If it makes any difference, the index is a `Date_Time` value and the `position` result should be the Date_Time index of `a`.

There will not be an `a` and `b` on the same line - they are the minimum and maximum of a (tank level) over time.

Comment: Will you please explain your logic a bit more? I'm having trouble digesting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use `bfill`, on column b but also on the index to get the position:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None,1,None,None,2,None], 'b': [None,None,None,3,None,4]})
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'position'})
df.loc[df['b'].isna(),'position'] = None
df.loc[df['a'].notna(),'position'] = df['position'].bfill()
df.loc[df['a'].isna(),'position'] = None
df.loc[df['a'].notna(),'value'] = df['b'].bfill()
df[['a','b', 'position', 'value']]
```

output

```
      a    b    position    value
--  ---  ---  ----------  -------
 0  nan  nan         nan      nan
 1    1  nan           3        3
 2  nan  nan         nan      nan
 3  nan    3         nan      nan
 4    2  nan           5        4
 5  nan    4         nan      nan
```

### Another solution

More elegant but perhaps slightly less readable. Same idea with `bfill` but now using `where`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None,1,None,None,2,None], 'b': [None,None,None,3,None,4]})
df['position'] = df.index.where(df['b'].notna())
df['position'] = df['position'].bfill().where(df['a'].notna())
df['value'] = df['b'].bfill().where(df['a'].notna())
```

Comment: Interesting answer; good job for understanding! ;) Note that you can do `col.notna()` instead of `~col.isna()` - it's slighly more readable. I've suggested an edit to your answer to that effect.

Comment: @piterbarg, I find the second solution easier to read than the first actually.  Late here in the UK but looks good & will try tomorrow :-)

Comment: @richardec good point thank you!